# WPF Image / Rendering Event

Tags: .net, wpf, image

I am using an Image control to display documents:

```
<Image x:Name="cImage" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ... />
```

Because it takes about half a second to display the image on the screen I first display a preview with:

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(cImage, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);
cImage.Source=...;
```

Then I set a timer to change the mode to HighQuality.

Is there an event that WPF fires when it has finished rendering that I could use instead of the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't that be the Loaded event for the image ?

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx, Loaded is launched when the content is rendered and ready for interaction.

Take note that if you change the content of the image control after it is loaded, the Loaded event won't be fired again.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the image sourceupdated event, but i do not always have any luck using this.

a better solution, depending on your source is to add a handler for when it is loaded.

you can try something like this:

```
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = tURI;
src.EndInit();
imgImage.SetCurrentValue(Image.SourceProperty, src);
src.DownloadCompleted += ImageDownloadCompleted;
```

then you can write the code for ImageDownloadCompleted to change the resolution.